# With my global hook installed, how do I know when a window begins to move and when it stops moving?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there an easy way to figure this out? I guess I can use WM_MOVE to tell me when it begins by keeping a timer. If the window has not received a WM_MOVE message within the last 2 seconds, then I know that it has just begun to move. Then I set another timer and wait for their not to be a message within a period of time (2 seconds). If nothing is received, then I can be confident that the window move has finished. Is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: You should use spy++ to see what messages are being passed and then handle the appropriate ones.

Comment: Rule 1 - don't use hooks.  Rule 2 - _really_ don't use global hooks. So, what kind of hook is it? ;)

Comment: of course it is ;). Well, so long as you never install it on _my_ machine, have a ball!

Comment: I write software for disabled persons and MSAA and UI automation only go so far. A global hook is the only way to do certain things and standard fare for this kind of software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a position to see `WM_MOVE` messages,  then you are also in a position to see [WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632622(VS.85).aspx) and [WM_EXITSIZEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632623(VS.85).aspx) messages.

Answer (score 1):

The window will receive a WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE message when moving begins, and WM_EXITSIZEMOVE when it ends.